# Mongodb CRUD Query

Tags: json, mongodb

How do i insert/delete/update second layer(address and age) of following json in mongodb?

```
{ 
   "name": "json",
   "profile": {
      "address": "jersey",
      "age":32

 }

}
```

Comment: Taewan, if one of the answers is adequate please "accept" the answer. Otherwise let us know how else we can help. Thanks.

Comment: If you need more information about CRUD operations in mongoDB take a look at this link: http://4dev.tech/2015/08/mongodb-basics-select-insert-update-and-delete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to increase the age of all users in the 'stuff' collection by 1, you'd do the following:

```
db.stuff.findAndModify({
  query: {"name": "json"}, 
  update: { $inc: { "profile.age": 1 } 
});
```

And to change the address, you'd do the following:

```
db.stuff.findAndModify({
  query: {"name": "json"}, 
  update: { "profile.address": "Blue Jays Way, Toronto" } 
});
```

I've found the [MongoDB Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/) and the (free) [MongoDB University course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about) to be incredibly helpful.

Comment: How about i want to change the value of address?

Comment: I've edited the response to include changing the address